# How to install Astrisk on 16.04 so that it works?

Tags: 16.04, asterisk

A plain installation of Asterisk onto 16.04 is not working for me. It writes dozens of lines of errors every 6 seconds.

The problem seems to be: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/asterisk/+bug/1458323

Is there a way to work around this?

(It seems bizarre that a major piece of software is broken on a major distro for years.)

Comment: The workaround is already detailed in the bug report. Feel free to step forward and lead the bug - organize testing and triage, coordinate upstream advice, etc. Ubuntu is a community effort.

Comment: Thanks, but that workaround just removed a module which I believe I will need.  This is my first go at using Asterisk.  Unfortunately I do not yet have the skills to even understand the bug, let alone fix it.